# Can all bases be orthonormalised? (Gram–Schmidt process).

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, orthonormal, gram-schmidt

I recently started learning about the [Gram–Schmidt process](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process), and I was wondering if it was possible to orthonormalise any basis? Or can we only orthonormalise specific bases? Why or why not?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: I want to say that Gram-Schmidt only works for up to and including countably infinite bases. Things start to get weird at uncountable bases.

Comment: The link you have given assumes finite basis. So yes, every finite basis can.